# Custom.css not actioned in PrestaShop 1.7

Tags: css, templates, prestashop-1.7

I have edited the custom.css file in PrestaShop 1.7 however, my changes are not being read and therefore not actioned.

I have looked at the source code for the front-end and can see that the custom.css file is loaded.. but opening the file I do not see the new css I have added. The file just displays the standard text message written into the custom.css file.

```
 /*
 * Custom code goes here.
 * A template should always ship with an empty custom.css
 */
```

The path is correct.
I have disabled the cache, and i've cleared the cache... but still no change.

How do I get PrestaShop to display the code I have written?

Many thanks.

Comment: what's the path to the custom.css file? Are you using a custom theme or the default theme?

Comment: Hi, I'm using the default theme "Classic" on Prestashop 1.7. The path is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting the shop1.json and shop2.json in /config/themes/

These are the old files PS is reading to display your site before your CSS changes. Delete these and when you load your shop again, new shop1.json and shop2.json files will be created that implement your template changes.